# How to determine AMD chipset driver version for BIOS update

Tags: freebsd, amd, freenas

I'm looking to update my BIOS on my Gigabyte GA-AB350M-DS3H. Currently it's running FREENAS 11.1-U7.  On the [BIOS page](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/GA-AB350M-DS3H-rev-1x/support#support-dl-bios) it says

```
Note: Update AMD Chipset Driver 18.10.20.02 or latest version before update this BIOS.
```

on the F24 BIOS. Is there a way I can verify my chipset drivers are up to date (or at least at this version) and I won't brick it with a BIOS update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“AMD Chipset Driver” refers to [the drivers for Windows](https://www.amd.com/en/support/chipsets/amd-socket-am4/x370); this isn’t a concern on FreeNAS.